# Paslode Impulse IM65 F16 Nailer's fan operation during normal use

Tags: woodworking, hardwood-floor, nails, hardwood-refinishing, nailing

Will the fan on a Paslode Impulse IM65 F16 Nail gun spin (whir) when the nail gun's firing muzzle is pressed against the surface to be nailed, if there is no fuel cell installed?
In other words, does the fan's operation depend on the presence of fuel cell?

I have an IM65 nailer but the fan is not spinning. I good battery installed (60% charged) but i have not installed fuel cell canister. I have taken out and tested the fan assembly and it spins normally when connected to a regular C type battery. The spark unit on the nailer is working fine and it sparks when the trigger is activated while the fan assembly is disconnected. Only problem is that the gun blinks red and green light if the muzzle is pressed on a surface in preparation for firing a nail.

I guess that the fan is ok and i am likely not informed enough about how the fan functions. I am assuming that the fan should spin if all steps are followed regardless of the presence of the fuel cell canister.
Can anyone here please help educate me.  Thanks all.